# How to access the number of rows accumulated by RETURNs in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql

When performing

```
RETURN QUERY ...
```

in a PL/pgSQL function, is it possible afterwards to directly access the number of rows accumulated into *the pile of records*, which are returned when the function ends?

Example:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tableA; -- 14 records
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tableB; -- 8 records
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tableC; -- 22 records
```

The number of accumulated records should now be 44.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;
```

Read the manual chapter [*"Obtaining the Result Status"*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS).
Your example could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test()
  RETURNS SETOF table_a
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   i  int;
   ct int := 0;
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM table_a;    -- 14 records
   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;  ct := ct + i;

   RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM table_b;    -- 8 records
   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;  ct := ct + i;

   RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM table_c;    -- 22 records
   GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;  ct := ct + i;

   RAISE NOTICE 'Returned % rows', ct;    -- 44
END
$func$;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kYsORtBY)