# UPDATE with LIMIT / OFFSET in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.2, plpgsql, pagination

In my Postgres 9.2 database I've got the following `SELECT`, which will be used by a PL/pgSQL function:

```
SELECT
      id
FROM
      tablea
WHERE
      migrated = false;
```

I want to get 2000 records each time and perform something like the following:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION migrate_data()
RETURNS integer AS
$$
declare
        row record;

BEGIN

FOR row IN EXECUTE '
        SELECT
              id
        FROM
              tablea
        WHERE
              migrated = false
'
LOOP

INSERT INTO tableb (id)
VALUES (row.id);

UPDATE tablea a SET migrated = yes WHERE a.id = row.id;

END LOOP;

RETURN num_rows; -- I want it to return the number of processed rows

END

$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

How can I tell the function to process 2000 records with every call? And it must start from where it left when on the next call.

Example:

```
select migrate_data(); -- id 0 to id 2000

select migrate_data(); -- id 2001 to id 4000

select migrate_data(); -- id 4001 to id 6000

select migrate_data(); -- id 6001 to id 8000
```

Etc.

Comment: BTW found this: [Five ways to paginate in Postgres, from the basic to the exotic](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/)

Comment: Is there concurrent write access to the source table? If yes, things get more sophisticated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a single SQL command with [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). Then get the row count with [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) in a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION migrate_data(OUT row_ct int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   WITH sel AS (
      SELECT id
      FROM   tablea
      WHERE  migrated = false
      ORDER  BY id   -- to proceed in deterministic order
      LIMIT  2000
      FOR    UPDATE  -- only for concurrent write access
      )
    , upd AS (
      UPDATE tablea a 
      SET    migrated = TRUE
      FROM   cte
      WHERE  a.id = sel.id
      )
   INSERT INTO tableb(id)
   TABLE  sel;  -- shorthand for: SELECT * FROM sel

   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;  -- writes to OUT param directly
END
$func$;
```

Related:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)
- [How to access the number of rows accumulated by RETURNs in PL/pgSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37433/how-to-access-the-number-of-rows-accumulated-by-returns-in-pl-pgsql/37438#37438)

You might just use the SQL statement without the function wrapper instead. Possibly as prepared statement.

Answer (score 3):

It will be much simpler (and faster) to use cursors for that:

```
begin;
declare foo cursor for
    SELECT
          id
    FROM
          tablea
    WHERE
          mig = true;
fetch forward 2000 from foo;
fetch forward 2000 from foo;
-- etc
rollback;
```

[About `declare`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-declare.html)
[About `fetch`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-fetch.html)

Comment: So... on your example, because there is 2 `fetch forward 2000 from foo;` calls the function will execute 4000 rows.. Did I understand right?

Comment: @PatrickB. There is no function. But yes, in my example there are 4000 rows will be fetched (or less if there are no so many rows).

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather prefer doing this using `pl/pgsql` as I'm more familiar...