# A simple example of how to use PLPGSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How can I define a query, and then run the query and a `SELECT COUNT(*)` (return the number of records) on that query's result?

I want results similar to:

```
postgres@127:postgres> (SELECT 1) union all (select 2) union all (select 3);
+----------+
| ?column? |
|----------|
| 1        |
| 2        |
| 3        |
+----------+
SELECT 3
Time: 0.049s
postgres@127:postgres> select count(*) from ((SELECT 1) union all (select 2) union
  all (select 3)) as q;
+-------+
| count |
|-------|
| 3     |
+-------+
SELECT 1
```

It must be a sql statement as I'm running this via pgcli which does not support terminal variables (https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli/issues/829).

---

I'm trying to use an anonymous PLPGSQL function but struggling to figure it out... And there are multitude of things I can look into next (anonymous code block, using non-anonymous function but then deleting it afterwards, return results from functions (a query instead of a set or rows?))  but I don't know what to focus on. I have this so far:

```
DO $$DECLARE v record;
BEGIN
  SELECT 10,20,30 into v;
END$$;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v;
```

Comment: What about creating a temp table? `create temp tables v as select ...;` then run `select count(*) from v;` but I don't understand why you can't run `select count(*) from (select ...) v;` directly?

Comment: I had the assumption that PLPGSQL would be some kind of scripting language and I could use it as a REPL environment, but that does not seem to be the case. 

I can run it directly, but if I'm  often changing the 'main' query that the others depend on (like the `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` it gets a bit cumbersome (text manipulation + number of button presses) having to copy/paste and rerun each query.

Comment: PL/pgSQL is a (procedural) programming language to write stored procedures and function. Maybe [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)  can help.

Comment: As for temporary tables - that probably will be helpful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For the given example

You shouldn't need PL/pgSQL, nor temp tables, nor CTEs for the task.
While combining queries with `UNION ALL` like in your example:

```
select count(*) from ((SELECT 1) union all (select 2) union all (select 3)) as q;
```

This is a much cheaper equivalent:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM <rest of qry1 here>)
     + (SELECT count(*) FROM <rest of qry2 here>)
     + (SELECT count(*) FROM <rest of qry3 here>) AS q;
```

Since `count(*)` never returns NULL, this is also NULL-safe.

If you cannot change the given `SELECT` queries at all, you can encapsulate them in subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT 1) q)
     + (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT 2) q)
     + (SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT 3) q) AS q;
```

Still (much) cheaper than building the whole result set before counting. (Just to throw it all away afterwards.)

#### Execute a query *and* get the result count

Use [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) in PL/pgSQL. Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test()
  RETURNS SETOF int
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   ct int;
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   (SELECT 1) UNION ALL (SELECT 2) UNION ALL (SELECT 3);
   GET DIAGNOSTICS ct = ROW_COUNT;

   RAISE NOTICE 'Returned % rows', ct;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_test();
```

See:

- [How to access the number of rows accumulated by RETURNs in PL/pgSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37433/how-to-access-the-number-of-rows-accumulated-by-returns-in-pl-pgsql/37438#37438)

Comment: Sorry my question likely was not very clear. I think it's just from my misunderstanding of how PLPGSQL can be used... But I was looking to run both the query and the count (as opposed to only the count) in basically one step.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: I added another answer above.